# How might I go about flagging a post or comment containing certain keywords?

Tags: nodes, flags

I have nodes coming in via FeedAPI and direct user submission, and I've got comments. A client requires me to check incoming nodes against a watch list of keywords. The posts and comments don't need to be blocked, because the watch list is fairly expansive (~1000 words but many are very context dependent). Rather, I need to be able to check the contents of a post or comment against the list and set a flag that triggers a notification to a moderator, who will manually review the content.

Is there a module that can help me with this? Barring a module, I could use a few clues to get me started on this, e.g.

"To check the content on a newly published node or comment, you could do these things."

"To flag based on a hit, you could do this thing."

Comment: We resolved it with a rule using custom PHP: We built a regexp around the blacklist, evaluated the node content against the regexp, and we send notifications to our compliance team if the PHP returns true.

Comment: There's also the "Text comparison" Rules condition, which may be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `hook_node_xyz` (d7) or `hook_nodeapi` (d6) to add code after node save or update.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using D6 because most related modules are not released in D7 yet. Here is an [overview](http://digcms.com/2011/03/19/profanity-filter-drupal/).

[Spam](http://drupal.org/project/spam) module hasn't been ported yet either.
[Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) is more of an automated service solution, don't think you can use your custom word list with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Search ApI for SolR](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module? I have not worked with it, but I have read a bit on it. SOLR search works on the Apache Database (if that is what you are using) and the module links it into Drupal.